# Restrict area for draw image object in canvas HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to restrict the area that an image can be drawn on a canvas. I am using Fabric.js.

I tried the following link, but it didn't work for me. [Set object drag limit in Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979644/set-object-drag-limit-in-fabric-js).

I want any part of the image that would be drawn outside the red rectangle (pictured below) to just not be drawn.[image]

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$("#canvascolor > input").click(function() {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(this.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  });
});
// trigger the first one at startup
$("#canvascolor > input:first-of-type()")[0].click();

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log("reader   " + reader);
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 140,
        top: 100,
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        angle: 0
      }).scale(0.9);
       oImg.lockMovementX = true;
     
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 0.8
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
};
```

```css
  canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#canvascolor input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
   <input type="file" id="file">
<canvas id="canvas" width="520" height="520"></canvas>
<section id="canvascolor">
  <input class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9leyl96qd3tytn8/tshirt-front.jpg">
  <input class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tk0fs5v4muo6898/tshirt-back.jpg">
</section>
<button href='' id='txt' target="_blank">submit</button><br/>
<img id="preview" />
```

Comment: Can you try to explain better what the user should should be able to do with the image?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi. Image should be draw in red line with rotate and zoom property..

Comment: what happens outside bounds? it should disappear the part outside or it should block moving?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi . It should be disappear.

Comment: @varunsharma. Yours is a duplicate question. The linked original question contains an answer plus a comment from FabricJS's creator: *"Watch 'object:moving', 'object:scaling', etc. events and constrain objects' left/top properties accordingly. – kangax"*

Comment: not really, he does  need to constrain movements like that other question, in this case the image is stopped horizontally and needs to be clipped outside the borders. Think of reopening it maybe

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi. Ok, reopened. :-)

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi. How to add clipboard.

Comment: Can we give limit drag in vertical.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi. I have seen your answer but i don't want image. But i want to give some limit to drag and scal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640471/fabric-js-constrain-resize-scale-to-canvas-object.

Comment: @markE thanks. Varunsharma this is not a chat. Make your question as clear and precise as possible and wait for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I extended your script to answer you.
For your use case it looks like you could use some clipping function and uniform centered scaling.

Anyway the main question about restricting area for drawing is this:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$("#canvascolor > input").click(function() {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(this.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  });
});
// trigger the first one at startup
$("#canvascolor > input:first-of-type()")[0].click();
function clipTShirt(ctx) {
   ctx.save();
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
   var x = 140, y = 100 ,w = 225, h = 300;
   ctx.moveTo(x, y);
   ctx.lineTo(x + w, y);
   ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
   ctx.lineTo(x, y + h);
   ctx.lineTo(x, y);
   ctx.restore();
}
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log("reader   " + reader);
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 140,
        top: 100,
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        angle: 0,
        lockUniScaling: true,
        centeredScaling: true,
        clipTo: clipTShirt
      }).scale(0.9);
       oImg.lockMovementX = true;
     
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 0.8
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
};
```

```css
  canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#canvascolor input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
   <input type="file" id="file">
<canvas id="canvas" width="520" height="520"></canvas>
<section id="canvascolor">
  <input class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9leyl96qd3tytn8/tshirt-front.jpg">
  <input class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tk0fs5v4muo6898/tshirt-back.jpg">
</section>
<button href='' id='txt' target="_blank">submit</button><br/>
<img id="preview" />
```