# Set object drag limit to a circle in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, fabricjs2

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979644/set-object-drag-limit-in-fabric-js). But instead of a rectangular boundary, I want it to be a circle

I tried working around on one of the answers from the previous question. Here's its [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flxf/qWc3q/) link. But haven't accomplished anything.

```
var boundingBox = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: "transparent",
  radius: 200,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
  evented: false,
  stroke: "red"
});
```

Comment: Check this:http://jsfiddle.net/cRxMa/. You need to adapt to work with fabricjs

Comment: thanks for the help but this refers to the center of the object(small circle). I want the edge of the object to say within the circle

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/freelast/6o0o07p7/ You need to use `clipto` functionality.

Comment: Here is an exemple with circle in circle:http://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/qWc3q/340/.

Comment: Thank you so much @MariusTurcu, you saved my life, but its only possible if the moving object is also a circle, if it is rectangle then a bit of the edge gets out of the boundary.

Comment: Hello @Observer, I could use it in other time but the specifications given to me was just to bound the object inside the circle. But thanks for the help!